# Spring cloud on cloud foundry : Connecting to RabbitMQ service not working

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, spring-rabbit

I have created a service instance of rabbitmq and bound it to my application which is a spring boot application with spring-cloud library support. When I try to run the application it fails saying the following.

```
2016-03-30T17:30:51.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT java.lang.IllegalStateException: In
valid configuration: 'virtualHost' must be non-null.
```

The code for the controller class method is the following.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rabbit")
public class RabbitController {
    @Autowired
    CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String onRootAccess() {

            if (rabbitConnectionFactory != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("Connected successfully to Redis!!!!!!!!  \n");
                sb.append("Host is " + rabbitConnectionFactory.getHost() + "\n ");
                sb.append("Port is " + rabbitConnectionFactory.getPort() + "\n ");
                sb.append("Virtual Host is " + rabbitConnectionFactory.getVirtualHost() + "\n ");

                AmqpAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
                Queue queue = admin.declareQueue();

                AmqpTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
                sb.append("Pushing data foo in myqueue Queue \n ");
                template.convertAndSend(queue.getName(), "foo");

                String foo = (String) template.receiveAndConvert(queue.getName());
                sb.append("Received data from myqueue is " + foo + "\n ");
                return sb.toString();
            } else {
                return "connection not successful";
            }
    }
```

The cf env shows the following details regading the rabbitmq service.

```
  "rabbitmq-3.5.6-lite": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "hostname": "10.3.1.1",
     "password": "lmprqrhu3gafazkn",
     "port": "32986",
     "ports": {
      "15672/tcp": "32985",
      "5672/tcp": "32986"
     },
     "uri": "amqp://z6nfr8blhtwena67:lmprqrhu3gafazkn@10.3.1.1:32986",
     "username": "z6nfr8blhtwena67"
    },
    "label": "rabbitmq-3.5.6-lite",
    "name": "rabbitmq-service",
    "plan": "free",
    "tags": [
     "rabbitmq",
     "mbus",
     "pubsub",
     "amqp"
    ]
   }
  ],
```

What could be the issue ? Any pointer to the solution would be of great help. Let me know if any more information is needed.

Regards,
Subhankar

Comment: Have you tried setting up a vhost and using it in your code?

Comment: @cantSleepNow No, The code I have shared is what I have done. Can you please throw some more light on this?

Comment: Simply try to use vhost other then default one, and see what happens. Here are some links https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: Found out something interesting. I was previously using springboot 1.3.2. Updating it to 1.3.3 solves the problem.